# Sources not being found in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm building an Android app with Eclipse and it all went well until I added a particular KeyEvent code. Once I tried to emulate my app, it crashed and died. I tried to clean it multiple times, but it is not being resolved. Also, when I try to edit the source path, the sources are shown for a split second but disappear. Here are the sources that are not being found:

```
ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 2159    
ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 2189 
ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread, ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 139    
ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Message) line: 1261  
ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 4894    
ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 784  
ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 551 
NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]
```

How can I make them become able to use? I am so close to my app being ready. This is the only setback in my app.

EDIT: Here's the logcat output:

```
08-12 10:52:02.359: E/AndroidRuntime(23219): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-12 10:52:02.359: E/AndroidRuntime(23219): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.mshaw.avanos/com.mshaw.avanos.AvanosActivity}:       java.lang.NullPointerException
08-12 10:52:02.359: E/AndroidRuntime(23219):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2075)
08-12 10:52:02.359: E/AndroidRuntime(23219):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2189)
08-12 10:52:02.359: E/AndroidRuntime(23219):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:139)
08-12 10:52:02.359: E/AndroidRuntime(23219):    at  android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1261)
08-12 10:52:02.359: E/AndroidRuntime(23219):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-12 10:52:02.359: E/AndroidRuntime(23219):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
08-12 10:52:02.359: E/AndroidRuntime(23219):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4894)
08-12 10:52:02.359: E/AndroidRuntime(23219):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-12 10:52:02.359: E/AndroidRuntime(23219):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-12 10:52:02.359: E/AndroidRuntime(23219):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
08-12 10:52:02.359: E/AndroidRuntime(23219):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
08-12 10:52:02.359: E/AndroidRuntime(23219):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-12 10:52:02.359: E/AndroidRuntime(23219): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-12 10:52:02.359: E/AndroidRuntime(23219):    at com.mshaw.avanos.SimpleEula.getPackageInfo(SimpleEula.java:25)
08-12 10:52:02.359: E/AndroidRuntime(23219):    at com.mshaw.avanos.SimpleEula.show(SimpleEula.java:33)
08-12 10:52:02.359: E/AndroidRuntime(23219):    at com.mshaw.avanos.AvanosActivity.<init>(AvanosActivity.java:36)
08-12 10:52:02.359: E/AndroidRuntime(23219):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
08-12 10:52:02.359: E/AndroidRuntime(23219):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
08-12 10:52:02.359: E/AndroidRuntime(23219):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1039)
08-12 10:52:02.359: E/AndroidRuntime(23219):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2066)
08-12 10:52:02.359: E/AndroidRuntime(23219):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Does the app work if you remove the KeyEvent code?

Comment: these sources are from framework, for which you wont have the code. Besides i dont think your crash is related to this part of code. It would be better if you post logcat output for the crash after you added a keyevent

Comment: No, it throws a NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps
1) Goto your debug view 
2) under Breakpoint Tab you will see NullPointerException
3) Right click and uncheck caught.
4) Debug your Project again

Hope this will help you. Thanks